# How to understand the result of this np.einsum('kij',A)?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

For example,

```
A = np.arange(24).reshape((2, 3, 4))
print np.einsum('ijk', A)
```

this is still `A` with no problem.

But if I do `print np.einsum('kij', A)` the shape is `(3, 4, 2)`. Shouldn't it be `(4, 2, 3)`?

The result of `print np.einsum('cab', A)` shape is `(4, 2, 3)` with no problem too. Why is `print np.einsum('kij', A)` not the same?

Comment: You must mean `A = np.arange(24).reshape((2,3,4))`

Comment: Also `np.einsum('cab', A).shape == (3, 4, 2)`, not `(4, 2, 3)`

Comment: I get `(3, 4, 2)` with both `kij` and `cab`.

Comment: I'd prefer an explicit reordering instruction, `kij->ijk`, or  `ijk->kij`. If there is still a question I could refer you to a pure Python version I reverse engineered a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify only a single set of subscripts, these are interpreted as the order of dimensions in the *input* array with respect to the *output*, not vice versa.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(24).reshape((2, 3, 4))
B = np.einsum('kij', A)

i, j, k = np.indices(B.shape)

print(np.all(B[i, j, k] == A[k, i, j]))
# True
```

As **@hpaulj** pointed out in the comments, you can make the correspondence between the input and output dimensions more explicit by specifying both sets of subscripts:

```
# this is equivalent to np.einsum('kij', A)
print(np.einsum('kij->ijk', A).shape)
# (3, 4, 2)

# this is the behavior you are expecting
print(np.einsum('ijk->kij', A).shape)
# (4, 2, 3)
```

Comment: imean when i use 'cab' the result shape is 4,2,3  but when i use 'kij' the result shape is 3，4，2 ，i think both of them should be ,2,3

Comment: I can't replicate the behaviour you're describing using either numpy v1.9.2, v1.8.2 or v1.6.0. I always get an output shape of `(3, 4, 2)` for both `np.einsum('kij', A)` and `np.einsum('cab', A)`.

Comment: Oh, I know now that what I want to do with 'kij' should be done using 'ijk->kij', but I still don't understand what 'kij' do why the result is (3,4,2)..

Comment: Suppose you labelled the dimensions of array `B` with the letters *i,j,k*. The positions of the letters in *k,i,j* then specifies the order in which you have to select the dimensions from array `A` in order to make array `B`. The first letter *i* is in the second position, so first dimension in `B` is the second dimension in `A` (3). The second letter *j* is in the third position, so the second dimension in `B` is the third dimension in `A` (4). The third letter *k* is in the first position, so the final dimension of `B` is the first dimension of `A` (2). Is that clearer?